# Sending hexidecimal numbers towards a login screen

Tags: python

I have a script that is designed to send an ENQ command (ASCII 005) when a user connects. If the user fails to provide an automated response, my script then sends "Who Are You". If no response is given to either the ENQ or the textual request, the user is dropped. The Textual part works but the it seems the client never sees the ENQ so an automatic response can be triggered.

I have done a lot of research and I can not seem to find the answer I am looking for. It seems correct, but it does not work. Normally Google will solve nearly any question I have, but in this case, I must be asking the question wrong.

This is Python 2.6.6.

```
def handle_send(self):

    if self.curr_state == self.started:
        return '\005'                               # Sends the control charactor E (ENQ)
    elif self.curr_state == self.waiting:
        return 'Who are you\r\n'                    # If no response to above, asks in plain language
    elif self.curr_state == self.connected:
        return 'GA+\r\n'                            # If the response is valid, this is hosting saying OK
    elif self.curr_state == self.terminated:
        return ''
    else:
        return ''
```

The normal valid response is "GA+", which means the system has accepted your ENQ response as valid. If you enter the valid information after it has given up on the automated ENQ response, it accepts the manually submitted valid data and allows you to proceed by giving you a "GA+".

All other parts of the application and the related programs work OK.

The issue is, I think is that I am not sending the ASCII character 005 correctly.

Comment: You have correctly specified a string with a single character with value Ctrl+E - do you need to follow it with `\r\n` in order to send it?

Comment: Hmm - so if I do not use \r\n\ it does not get sent? I knew that applied to traditional text but was not sure about non printable characters.

Comment: I just tried it with the changes and no luck.

Comment: Have you checked that the `self.curr_state == self.started` expression evaluates to `True` so the ENQ can be sent? Additionally, does the user definitely require the hexadecimal ENQ character, or does the user require the ordinal ENQ (5) integer?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was attempting to send the control character E to the end user. I have tried the "005" "05" and "5" without luck. When I look at the connection (from another host), I can see it is waiting its 5 seconds (as specified) before then sending the textual version ("Who are you"). If I could figure how to post the error I see on a login, I would.